# Error: Cannot create FMOD::Sound instance for resource sharedassets0.resource when splitting application binary in Unity

Tags: unity, android

I'm trying to publish an Unity app to the PlayStore. Since the size of the app is over the limit of 100MB, I need to split the binary. So I selected the option **Split Application Binary** in Unity.

However, when I try to launch this application (either by downloading it on the Playstore or putting the .apk and the .obb directly on my device from my computer), I get the following errors on Android SDK monitor:

```
01-24 11:38:52.442: E/Unity(25004): Error: Cannot create FMOD::Sound instance for resource 
sharedassets0.resource, (File not found. )
01-24 11:38:52.442: E/Unity(25004):  
01-24 11:38:52.442: E/Unity(25004): (Filename:  Line: 882)
01-24 11:38:52.442: E/Unity(25004): Function SoundHandle::Instance::~Instance() may only be 
called from main thread!
01-24 11:38:52.442: E/Unity(25004):  
01-24 11:38:52.442: E/Unity(25004): (Filename:  Line: 25)
```

The application freezes at the "*Made with Unity*" splash screen.

This is not happening when I don't use the **Split Application Binary** option and put the .apk directly on my device from my computer.

I'm using Unity 5.4.0.